# probability problem (infinite repeat)

Tags: probability

In this problem $A_1$ ,$A_2$ ,$A_3$ are events and $P(A_1)=t_1$, $P(A_2)=t_2$, $P(A_3)=t_3$, and $S=\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$.

I want to find the probability that event $A_2$ occurs after $A_1$ (or $A_1$ occurs before $A_2$).

*Note:*

1) Each experiment is independent.

2) Each experiment is repeated "infintely".

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the probability that $A_1$ occurs before $A_2$; call that event a *success*. Consider what happens on the first experiment. With probability $t_1$ event $A_1$ occurs, and with probability $1$ we have a success. With probability $t_2$ event $A_2$ occurs, and we have a failure; i.e., the probability of success at this point is $0$. And with probability $t_3$ event $A_3$ occurs, and it’s as if we were starting over from the beginning: the probability of a success starting from here is $p$. Thus, $p$ is a weighted sum of the conditional probabilities $1$, $0$, and $p$ of success after events $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$, respectively. Can you now write down an equation expressing this and solve it for $p$ in terms of $t_1,t_2$, and $t_3$? (You can actually get it in terms of $t_1$ and $t_2$ if you remember to use the fact that $t_1+t_2+t_3=1$.)

Comment: I really didn't understood your hint.can you explain more and write out the equation?

Comment: @jini25: I’d prefer not to write out the equation, because then there’s almost nothing left for you to do. Let $S$ be the event of a success. For $k=1,2,3$ let $B_k$ be the event that the first outcome is $A_k$. Then $\Bbb P(S\mid B_1)=1$: if the first outcome is $A_1$, we’re certain to have a success. $\Bbb P(S\mid B_2)=0$, because if the first outcome is $A_2$, we’re certain **not** to have a success. And $\Bbb P(S\mid B_3)=p$, because if the first outcome is $A_3$, we’re nothing has changed. $\Bbb P(S\mid B_k)\Bbb P(B_k)=\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_k)$, and $\Bbb P(B_k)=t_k$. Thus, we can ...

Comment: ... write $$\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_1)+\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_2)+\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_3)$$ in terms of $p,t_1,t_2$, and $t_3$. But exactly one of the events $B_1,B_2$, and $B_3$ must occur, so $$\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_1)+\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_2)+\Bbb P(S\text{ and }B_3)=\Bbb P(S)=p\;.$$ Fill in the pieces, and you’ll have your equation.

Comment: why p(s|b3)=p or p(s)=p? I still can't know main answer?if you write complete answer , help me to understand.thanks.

Comment: @jini25: Since I defined $p$ to be the probability of a success and $S$ to be the event of a success, of course $\Bbb P(S)=p$: it’s true by the way I defined the symbols $p$ and $S$. I’ve explained twice why $\Bbb P(S\mid B_3)=p$: if the first outcome is $A_3$, the probability of eventually getting a success has not changed. The $A_3$ is irrelevant: it does not make an eventual success either more or less likely. Thus, $\Bbb P(S\mid B_3)$, the probability of eventual success when the first outcome is $A_3$, is the same as $\Bbb P(S)$, which by definition is $p$.

Comment: how to import infintely condition in answer?

Comment: @jini25: You don’t need to: the analysis that I gave avoids having to consider any specifics after the first trial. There are other, much more complicated ways to solve the problem that involve writing down and evaluating infinite summations, but this way is much easier.

Comment: could we didn't define Bk?

Comment: @jini25: I defined it in my very long comment above: For $k=1,2,3$ let $B_k$ be the event that the first outcome is $A_k$.